# Sequelize setting association owner id "number | { [CreationAttributeBranch: true; }" is not assignable to number

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

When copying the TypeScript manual, using Project.create() when manually setting the ownerId, it errors out.
In clarification, the following code:

```
const ab = Project.create({ name: 'abc', ownerId: newUser.get('id') })
```

Errors out`Type 'number | { [CreationAttributeBrand]: true; }' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type '{ [CreationAttributeBrand]: true; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.`
Using the built in user.createProject works, but manually attempting create a standalone doesn't work correctly. I understand why it's happening, but I need a workaround because the actual model I have has multiple associations to create.

You can get the same code by copying https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html example and adding the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Sequelize v6.13. It was fixed later on. Updating versions fixed it. (The return value was `number | { [CreationAttributeBrand]...}` When it was supposed to be `number &` )

Answer (score 0):

For my case I set id to any:

```
export interface ProjectInfoDto {
  // id: number;
  id: any;
  name: string;
  ownerId: number;
}
```